# jsf datatable limiting user result

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I was wondering how could I be able to show users warning or information to refine the search if their search result exceeds 100. For example: if the search results are more than 100 then display only hundred and show users warning to refine the search, in JSF/datatable.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
query.setMaxResults(4);
```

I think i got it.

Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

- limit the list size in your managed bean. Preferably, set a limit to the SQL result (or whatever persistence mechanism you are using)
- set a `boolean shouldRedefineCriteria` (in the managed bean) in case the result is bigger than 100. If you have limited the SQL result, you can safely specify:

  ```
  shouldRedefineCriteria = result.size() >= 100;
  ```
- in your jsf page output:

  ```
  <h:outputText value="Redefine your criteria" 
       rendered="#{managedBean.shouldRedefineCriteria" />
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your time.I am using JPA.

Comment: then use `query.setMaxResult()` to limit the result of the query